# How to see kernel time variables without using adjtimex?

Tags: kernel, proc

The `man` page for `adjtimex` says

> Anyone may print out the time variables, but only the superuser may change them.

How do I see the value shown by `adjtimex -p` as the `tick` variable without using `adjtimex`? I've browsed around in `/proc/sys/kernel` as well as some in `/sys` but haven't yet found anything that shows me that value.

(I'm running `Debian Jessie` on a an ARM development board)

Comment: It's `unsigned long tick_usec` in the kernel. You can possibly use a kernel debugger or systemtap to view it, but the documented interface is the adjtimex system call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted by @MarkPlotnick, there is no `/sys` or `/proc` interface for this. You have to use a program like `adjtimex` to make the appropriate system calls to see it.